# basic jquery slider next text not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery('#slider-container').bjqs({
  'animation' : 'slide',
  'width' : 1060,
  'height' : 500,
  'showControls' : false,
  'centerMarkers' : false,
  animationDuration: 500,
  rotationSpeed: 5000
});
jQuery('#quotes-slider').bjqs({
  'animation' : 'slide',
  'width' : 760,
  'height' : 135,
  'showControls' : false,
  'centerMarkers' : false,
  nexttext : 'Next', // Text for 'next' button (can use HTML)
  prevtext : 'Prev',
  animationDuration: 500,
  rotationSpeed: 5000
});
```

I use this function but my 2nd slider does not show next and previous functon kindly help me

Comment: could you post more code, also errors you are getting in console in developer tools

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly set that you want to show the controls using `showcontrols`:

```
jQuery('#quotes-slider').bjqs({
  showcontrols : true,
  nexttext : 'Next', // Text for 'next' button (can use HTML)
  prevtext : 'Prev'
});
```